# Asp.Net Core Mvc and Angular 4 (2) routing

Tags: c#, angular, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, angular-routing

I'm trying to use angular 2 on a Visual studio Asp.Net Core MVC project (c#).

I've already embed Angular 2 and Typecript into the project and I've configured everything to display content (with design material).

**I would like to use the classic MVC structure with controllers and views, and I would like to use the views of the structure as pages for the Angular components templateUrl.**

I work with the areas but I do not think this can affect the answer.
For now I have managed to do all this with Angular routing, but I have some problems since the content is rendered twice for the first screen (First view rendered from controller because RenderBody render the page and after the angular route is used) that is opened.

This is the routing (Angular):

```
    ...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'Authentication/Auth/Login',
            component: LoginComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'Admin/Home/Dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'Admin/Home/Contact',
            component: ContactComponent
        }
    ];
```

This is app module:

```
        ...
@NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            ...
            AppRouting,
            BrowserAnimationsModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            DashboardComponent,
            ContactComponent,
            LoginComponent
        ],
        bootstrap: [ 
            AppComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
        ]
    })
```

This is the areas structure:

[Areas structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WmQw.png)

This is the layout html page (in shared, LayoutAngular.cshtml):

```
...
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Material -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/indigo-pink.css" />

    @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Root angular -->
    <angular-app-component></angular-app-component>

    @RenderBody()

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="~/lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="~/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err)
        {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
    ...
```

The *angular-app-component* is an Angular component; this is the code:

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'angular-app-component',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

This is the Dashboard component (dashboard.component.ts):

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-component',
    templateUrl: "/Admin/Home/Dashboard" // This is load template from controller View (Areas/Admin/Controllers/Home/Dashboard, this is a simple return View) to Mvc View in (Areas/Admin/Views/Home/Dashboard.cshtml)
})
export class DashboardComponent {
}
```

So is there a way to use the MVC structure with the views in cshtml (since they are currently rendered correctly with @RenderBody), but using Angular 2 routing (also because refresh not work with this configuration)?
I would like to avoid inserting the html pages and the Angular components in the wwwroot (currently in wwwroot are inserted angular scripts generated with SystemJS).

Thanks.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<angular-app-component></angular-app-component>` from your `_Layout.cshtml` and place it alone inside your `Index.cshtml` file(s). This will then render `<angular-app-component></angular-app-component>` where you call `@RenderBody()`.

Then simply ensure the rest of your views, i.e. those that get rendered from the call to `Authentication/Auth/Login`, have `Layout = null` set within the templates so the Layout doesn't get rendered again.

Comment: By doing this, the first page that will be loaded (the first url after debug start) will be rendered twice because the first render is performed by_Layout @RenderBody and the second by Angular that renders the TemplateUrl.
Then the content is displayed twice.
[Screenshot of page after render](http://imgur.com/a/5ObLT)